# convergent series diverges when expanding and collecting terms

Tags: summation, divergent-series

I have a series

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-rx}}{ln(r+1)}$$

Which converges for $x \geq 0$ and then I expand the exponential in the sum to get

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ln(r+1)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-rx)^n}{n!}$$

And collect the r terms to get

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} G_{n} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
where
 $$G_{n}=\sum_{r=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-r)^n}{\ln {r}}$$

But $G_n$ is a divergent series right? Did I do it wrong or is it because of something else?

Comment: You can't really split it up like that. $1\over ln(r+1)$ diverges.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to split it into a nicer sum? @Andrew